# Background Color changes while printing file in Gedit

Tags: linux, ubuntu, print-to-pdf, gedit

How do I change the background color of the pdf file while printing an opened file in Gedit. I try to print the opened file it uses the syntax highlighting but doesn't use the background color of the color schema I use for syntax highlighting, and changes it to White.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible right now and there is an [open issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gedit/-/issues/491) on their gitlab with a similar request. Quote from there:

> It is planned to rework a bit the printing feature in gedit, to first
> show the preview and do the configuration from there. We will see how
> to better handle the color scheme.

For now you need to either change the color scheme to be more friendly for printing or  use a different editor.